# Subtract offset from the current time using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, timezone-offset

I need to get subtract the timezone offset from the current time using momentjs

Suppose I have below offsets

1) +05:30
2) -05:00
3) -06:30

Now I need to subtract this time from the current time

```
moment(). // what should be here?
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: RAJESH Not working with my nodejs. `const date = moment.utc().utcOffset("-04:00")`

Comment: @Luke - no, you don't add or subtract a time zone offset. You apply it.

Comment: @Profer - you'll have to do better than "not working".  What doesn't work?  That code looks fine to me.

Comment: @MattJohnson `const date = moment.utc().utcOffset("-04:00")` It does not add offset to the current time. neither add nor subtract

Comment: @MattJohnson Actually I use `.toDate()` as well. Something like `const date = moment.utc().utcOffset("-04:00").toDate()`

Comment: `Date` objects only track a specific timestamp - a unique moment in time.  Adding or subtracting would give a different moment in time.  Thus rightfully, adjusting the offset or time zone of how one views that moment should not change the moment or the underlying timestamp itself.  See also: https://dilbert.com/strip/1998-03-14

Comment: To be more direct - don't call `.toDate()`.  Instead use `.format()` to produce the desired string.

Comment: That question is about adding a duration of time.  5 hours and 30 minutes after the current time.  It isn't the same as applying a time zone offset.  In other words, just because India's local time is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of UTC, doesn't mean that events occur 5 hours and 30 minutes later in real-time.  It just means the local clocks are offset by that amount.

Comment: Put another way:  If I were to set my clock to India's local time, and you were to set your clock to UTC, both clocks would be correct for their purpose.  If I were to then send you a message over the internet, you would not have to wait 5 hours and 30 minutes to receive it.  You'd still receive it almost instantly.